# Register Custom Generic type in AutoMapper

Tags: automapper

i want register custo generic type like default generic type that register in autoMaper (like List, Array) in AutoMappper.

i have one generic type in project this Code :

```
class PagedResult<T>
{
    public List<T> PageOfResults { get; set; }

    public int TotalItems { get; set; }
}
```

and Dto Class is:

```
class StudentDto
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and VM Model is :

```
class StudentVM
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and service class:

```
class MyServie
{
    public PagedResult<StudentDto> Swap()
    {
        var test2 = new PagedResult<StudentDto>();
        test2.PageOfResults = new List<StudentDto>();
        test2.PageOfResults.Add(new StudentDto() { ID = 10, Name = "Ten" });
        test2.TotalItems = 10;

        return test2;
    }
}
```

i want use from AutoMapper Object Manager for register PagedResult<> in automapper but i can not do this

```
var allMappers = MapperRegistry.AllMappers();

MapperRegistry.AllMappers = () => new IObjectMapper[]{
     new IdentifiableMapper(),
}.Concat(allMappers);

var service = new MyServie();
PagedResult<StudentDto> pageableStudentDto = service.Swap();

Mapper.CreateMap<StudentDto, StudentVM>();;

PagedResult<StudentVM> vm = Mapper.Map<PagedResult<StudentDto>, PagedResult<StudentVM>>(pageableStudentDto);
```

and implement of

```
public class PageOfMapper : IObjectMapper
{
    public bool IsMatch(ResolutionContext context)
    {
        return typeof(PagedResult<>).IsAssignableFrom(context.SourceType.GetGenericTypeDefinition()) &&
            typeof(PagedResult<>).IsAssignableFrom(context.DestinationType.GetGenericTypeDefinition());
        //return true;
    }

    public object Map(ResolutionContext context, IMappingEngineRunner mapper)
    {
        // please help me in this code for map ******************

        return null;
    }
}
```